# How to create the particular Flutter widgets shown in the screenshot

Tags: flutter, user-interface

Click on the link below to find the widget

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this repo for [slider](https://github.com/serenader2014/flutter_carousel_slider) as you want :

Here is the sample code:

```
CarouselSlider.builder(
  itemCount: 15,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex, int pageViewIndex) =>
    Container(
      child: Text(itemIndex.toString()),
    ),
)
```

For more examples: https://serenader2014.github.io/flutter_carousel_slider/#/